# What does the time next to the cell phone icon mean?

Tags: facebook

I noticed that a time value lies next to each cell phone icon in Facebook chat.

[image]

What does this time value indicate?

Comment: This question doesn't meet the [current quality standards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It had been 50 minutes since the user is away from Facebook web app and is available on FB mobile.